# Connecting traveling sine wave & rotating point on circle

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

Please help me to select the green sphere (A) and get its y coordinate so that the mesh line is connected to the icosphere on the circle.
[image]
Blender file is available here: [image]

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

To capture the position of an instance, it must be "realized" first. But to not realize all instances, as only the last one is of interest, a copy is made using a *Duplicate Elements* node set in *Instance* domain. The number of instances is recovered by a *Domain Size* node set in *Instance* domain also. Then all instances but the one with the last index, i.e. the *Instance Count* minus 1, are deleted. The remaining instance is finally realized. Its barycentre is computed using an *Attribute Statistic* node as the mean of its vertices position.

[image: GN graph]

**Resources:** [image]